# Should i have Exception-Types in Interface-Assembly? Best practices?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I have an assembly which contains only interfaces to avoid unnessesary dependecies. Now i have an exception-type named `UndefinedIHttpMacTokenException`. So as you can see the exception concerns an interface-type of `IHttpMacToken`. Now i thought it would be best to include the exception-type in the interface-assembly. But this is a bit contradictory. If you hear the assemblys name (somenamespace.Interfaces). You would not expect it to contain class-types(exceptions).

So can you help me out? What is best practice in such cases?
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: An assembly can contain multiple namespaces. You can use a different namespace for the exceptions.

Comment: I don't think this is contradictory, you are just confusing interfaces as a concept with interfaces as a code artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If implementations of your interfaces are expected to throw certain exceptions under some specific circumstances, then the corresponding exception should be part of the assembly containing the interfaces. In a sense, exceptions thrown by your code are part of the interface of your assembly, even though exceptions are represented by classes, not by interfaces.

Moreover, if your interfaces use specific classes that you do not allow your users to extend (i.e. sealed classes) you should include these classes as well. Finally, all `enum`s should be part of the assembly too.

Look at `System.Data` assembly for a good example of how a major component of .NET does this. Main purpose of the assembly is to provide fifteen interfaces to be implemented for accessing databases from .NET. All exception classes, classes used as parameters and return values, and `enum`s are part of `System.Data` as well.

Comment: Great Answer. Thank you =)